# What is the equivalent of Chrome's "add source map" in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, source-maps, firefox-developer-tools

On chrome I can add a custom source map url for my `bundle.js`.

From the chrome sources panel, I can click on `bundle.js` then right-click inside the source window and I have the option `add source map`. How can I achieve the same in firefox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is currently no way to do this in the Firefox developer tools.  There is [a bug in bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=992268) for it though.